# MultipleSelect plugin setSelects method doesn't work with a string

Tags: jquery, multiple-select

I am using [that](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/#methods) plugin in a site that im building now. As you can see it has a method called `setSelects` that selects values from the select item with this way `$('select').multipleSelect('setSelects', [1, 3]);`

So i have a variable called `$catList` that if you alert it, returns :

`'proj-books','proj-pub','poet-perf','poet-exh','theo-lec','theo-vids','arch-aud','arch-obj'`

now im trying to pass that variable into the method mentioned above but without any luck.

```
$('.select-categories').multipleSelect('setSelects', [$catList] );
$('.select-categories').multipleSelect('refresh');
```

The weird is that if i change the above code into this :

```
$('.select-categories').multipleSelect('setSelects', ['proj-books','proj-pub','poet-perf','poet-exh','theo-lec','theo-vids','arch-aud','arch-obj'] );
$('.select-categories').multipleSelect('refresh');
```

everything works.

The problem is that i want to pass that value through catList variable and not that way.

Can you suggest me a possible way to fix it ?

Thank you.

P.S i saw that the type of this method is array and so maybe this is the problem but i cannot image a way to convert my string into an array so to make it work.

Comment: So is `$catList` an array? If ya, use it like this: `$('.select-categories').multipleSelect('setSelects', $catList );` If it is a string, then just split it: `$('.select-categories').multipleSelect('setSelects', $catList.split(',') )`

Comment: Is `$catList` an array? You are wrapping `$catList` in an array before calling the `multipleSelect` function.

Comment: Thank you. The tip with split worked cause the $catList was a string.